# Time complexity of two different solution for Bubble Sort

Tags: algorithm, bubble-sort

I made a solution for Bubble sort in two ways.
One is checking from begins to ends every time. And the other is also checking from begins to ends, but 'ends' is getting smaller(-1). Because we can assure that the last one is sorted when every loop is finished.

In my opinion, the time complexity of the first one is O(n^2) and the other's is O(nlogn). Is it right?

#### first

```js
var bubbleSort = function(array) {
    // Your code here.

    let changed = true;
    let temp;
    while(changed){
      changed = false
      for(let i=0 ; i<array.length-1 ; i++){
        if(array[i] > array[i+1]){
          temp = array[i+1];
          array[i+1] = array[i];
          array[i] = temp;
          changed = true;
        }
      }
    }
    return array;

};
```

#### second

```js
var bubbleSort = function(array) {
    // Your code here.
    let temp;

    for(let i=0 ; i<array.length-1 ; i++){
      for(let j=0 ; j<array.length-1-i ; j++){
        if(array[j]>array[j+1]){
          temp = array[j+1];
          array[j+1] = array[j];
          array[j] = temp;
        }
      }
    }
    return array;
};
```

Comment: No, both are O(n^2)

Comment: Only the first algorithm is Bubble Sort. The second is a variation on Selection Sort. The inner loop processes a smaller and smaller unsorted partition of the array. It moves the highest item to the end of the top of the unsorted partition and then moves the partition fence so that the item is now in the sorted one.

Comment: Well, we might call the second function a "bubbly-flavored (effervescent?) selection sort". It chooses the highest item by swapping, which causes other items to bubble up closer to the top of the unsorted array.  A canonical selection sort uses some sort of "find max" function to find the highest item to be removed and put into the sorted sequence. I.e. a selection sort is normally not an exchange sort, but here it is turned into an exchange sort.

Answer (score 2):

Both versions of bubble sort are O(n²) in the worst case and also in the average case.

The first version, which I call "naive bubble sort", has an outer loop and an inner loop. The inner loop iterates n-1 times, and the outer loop also iterates up to n-1 times. This fact can be proven as a corollary of the fact that the second version (where the outer loop is limited to n-1 iterations) is correct. So the worst case number of iterations is (n-1) * (n-1) = O(n²). Its best case running time is O(n), but this happens rarely enough that the average is still O(n²).

The second version, which is the one normally referred to as "bubble sort", has an outer loop which iterates n-1 times, and an inner loop which iterates n-1-i times. Since i is on average about n/2, the number of iterations is approximately n * n/2 = O(n²). There is no short-circuiting, so this is the best, worst and average case for this version of the algorithm.

The average case for both algorithms is O(n²) because of a fundamental fact about the bubble sort algorithm: it performs one swap per [inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_(discrete_mathematics)) in the input array. An inversion is a pair of indices whose elements are out of order. There are a total of (n choose 2) = n * (n-1) / 2 pairs, and on average half of them will be inversions. To see this, consider that if an array has k inversions, then the reverse of that array has (n choose 2) - k inversions. So, either version of bubble sort does an average of n * (n-1) / 4 swaps, which is O(n²).